# How can I convert Mat to Bitmap using OpenCVSharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, c#-4.0

First, I tried this,

```
    public static Bitmap MatToBitmap(Mat mat)
    {
        return OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(mat);
    }
```

[image]

So, then, I tried this,

```
    public static Bitmap MatToBitmap(Mat mat)
    {
        mat.ConvertTo(mat, MatType.CV_8U);
        return OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(mat);
    }
```

The image is completely black,

[image]

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertMatToBitmap(Mat matToConvert) 
    {            
        return new Bitmap(matToConvert.Cols, matToConvert.Rows, 4*matToConvert.Rows, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed, matToConvert.Data);
    }
```

This doesn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using `Mat` type, I suggest you to use `IplImage` type. Take the following example code as reference (I use VisualStudio2013 with OpenCvSharp2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenCvSharp;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TestOpenCVSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read the Lenna image
            IplImage inputImage = new IplImage(@"Lenna.png");

            // Display the input image for visual inspection
            new CvWindow("original image", inputImage);
            Cv.WaitKey();

            // Convert into bitmap
            Bitmap bitimg = MatToBitmap(img);                
            // Save the bitmap
            bitimg.Save(@"bitmap.png");
        } // end of main function

        // This is the function that converts IplImage image
        // into Bitmap
        public static Bitmap MatToBitmap(IplImage image)
        {
            return OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
        } // end of MatToBitmap function
    } // end of class definition
}  // end of namespace definition
```

This is your input Lenna image:

[image]

And this is the `bitmap.png` that is created from `Bitmap` type:

[image]

Hope it helps!

**Update:**

By using OpenCVSharp3, the following code can also convert a `Mat` type into `Bitmap` type:

```
Mat image = new Mat(@"Lenna.png");
Cv2.ImShow("image", image);
Cv2.WaitKey();

Bitmap bitimg = MatToBitmap(image);
// Save the bitmap
bitimg.Save(@"bitmap.png");
```

with the function:

```
public static Bitmap MatToBitmap(Mat image)
{
   return OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
} // end of MatToBitmap function
```

And the obtained result is the same as shown above.

Comment: it it impossible to convert mat to bitmap?

Comment: could you provide your code for creating mat so that I can better evaluate?

Answer (score 6):

The others solutions *almost* worked for me.
The bitmaps were there, but sometimes an exception saying that the `encoder` was `null` was threw.

I solved using the following code.

```
private static Bitmap MatToBitmap(Mat mat) {
    using (var ms = mat.ToMemoryStream()) {
        return (Bitmap) Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the other solutions work with OpenCVSharp 4.

Answer (score 3):

mat have a method that return Bitmap:

```
        mat.ToBitmap(bitmap);
```

"using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;" is also needed for this.

Comment: Yes, you can do this but you can't use the Bitmap after the Mat is disposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions; 

Mat mat = new Mat(@"Lenna.png");
Bitmap bitmap = mat.ToBitmap();
```

You have to use OpenCvSharp.Extensions which can be installed from NuGet by searching "OpenCvSharp4.Extensions".